# Maven android plugin error "constant expression required"

Tags: android, maven

I am writing maven build scripts for my project which has dependency to another android project as *apklib*. When I execute

> mvn clean install

goal `generate-sources` executes successfully. But, `R.java` generated for *apklib* project contains non-constant variables i.e. `public static int`. So, that causes error

> constant expression required

during compile time. My question is can I change default maven android plugin behaviour that passes argument `--non-constant-id` to aapt tool. Or you can suggest any other solution as well.

Details of build configuration:

> Android plugin version: 3.6.0 
>   Platform: 8 Platform version: 2.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is causing, because resource ids are used inside switch case. And switch case requires constants. So, I am changing switch cases inside my APKLIB project to if-else statements. Please suggest if any other solution.